# Elastic Beanstalk with Laravel Envoy

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-envoy

I write a bash script to run the laravel envoy command in Elastic Beanstalk.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/app/current/
sudo php vendor/bin/envoy run fillData &
```

And it gives errors as:

> Unsuccessful command execution on the instance

And when accessing the EC2 terminal and running the command, it works fine with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue

As if found this `WARN` in elastic beanstalk AWS

> The following instances have not responded in the allowed command
> timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own)

As I understand the command continued running and did not stop

I found this article

[fixing-a-mysterious-ebextensions-command-time-out-aws-elastic-beanstalk](https://blog.jakubholy.net/2015/07/29/fixing-a-mysterious-ebextensions-command-time-out-aws-elastic-beanstalk/)

and I wrote this command in bash file

```
nohup sudo php vendor/bin/envoy run fillData >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

`nohup` command to run  in the background, `>/dev/null` and it will put all the results on
so it will ignore the result
you can find more details about
[>/dev/null](https://medium.com/@codenameyau/step-by-step-breakdown-of-dev-null-a0f516f53158)